# How to get height of UL element when display is set to flex

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, flexbox

I am doing blockwise segregation of elements of a webpage and drawing border around those blocks but I noticed `height` will be `0` if `display` is set to `flex`. How can I get the height in such cases? I tried few methods but all give `0`

```
ul.offsetHeight // gives me 0
ul.clientHeight // gives me 0
ul.getBoundingClientRect() //gives me 0
window.getComputedStyle(ul).height //gives me 100%

//This also gives me 0
var range = document.createRange()
range.selectNodeContents(ul)
range.getBoundingClientRect()
```

**EDIT**

This is nothing to do with `flex` property. It was giving `0` just because it was not visible on the screen only. I don't want to delete the question as already I took few people's time

Comment: Can you provide fiddle?

Comment: If you made a mistake, and in cases like this, where actually nothing where wrong, this question and its answers, which doesn't add anything that you already didn't yourself, has no meaningful value for future users, you should delete it, or close it as _This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced_.

Comment: @LGSon Ok Closing it

Answer (score 2):

Are you dynamically creating your element? It's possible that you're trying to pull the height before it's been created. Giving the div an id and calling its height property works fine for me, so you're either pulling the data too early or you've set the height to 0 yourself somewhere.

Alternatively, if you're trying to call every ul element at a time rather than a specific one, you need to get the height of the individual array output, i.e. `ul[0]`.

```js
//Single Call
document.getElementById('one').innerHTML = document.getElementById('someDiv').clientHeight;

//Multi Call
var multi = document.getElementsByTagName('ul');
document.getElementById('two').innerHTML = multi[1].clientHeight;
```

```css
ul {
  background: #f00;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <ul id="someDiv">
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li>Three</li>
  </ul>
</p>
<p>
  <ul id="anotherDiv">
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li>Three</li>
    <li>Four</li>
  </ul>
<p>
<p>First ul Height: <span id="one"> - </span></p>
<p>Second ul Height: <span id="two"> - </span></p>
```

Comment: No worries, thanks for not deleting your question - it might help someone in the future. :)

Answer (score -1):

I just tried like this,

```js
document.write(document.querySelector('ul').offsetHeight);
```

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>a</li>
  <li>a</li>
  <li>a</li>
  <li>a</li>
</ul>
```